# Must I change the admin user email address while changing the general email address?

Tags: email, wp-mail

I changed the email at Settings > General from me@gmail.com to info@mysite.com. It seems like the email didn't change, although I received the confirmation email to change. I'm still receiving emails from me@gmail.com.

Do I still need to change the Administrator email under Users to info@mysite.com for the change to take effect?

Using WP 5.1.3

Answer (score 1):

The email address that emails such as new user notification or password resets come "from" is not the same as the site's admin email.  While it's possible to have the actual email address *be* the same for both of these, they are completely unrelated to each other.

In WP's Settings > General, the "Administration Email Address" is the email address used to administer the site.  This is saved in the WP db options table (`wp_options`) as "admin_email".

This value should not be confused with the "from" email address that emails going through `wp_mail()` will come from (or appear to be coming from).  These are two entirely different things.

If you want to change the address that emails come from, you need to do one of two possible things:

1. Filter the "from" address for `wp_mail()` using the [`wp_mail_from`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from) and [`wp_mail_from_name`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from_name) filters.
2. [Configure `wp_mail()` to send through an authenticated SMTP account](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75956/whats-the-easiest-way-to-setup-smtp-settings-programmatically) or [install a plugin to do it for you](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/smtp/).

**Update:**
It sounds like you might already be using one of the two above methods to change the "from" address.  You'll need to update that accordingly if you're changing the email address.

Comment: I'm referring to the admin email under WP's Settings > General. I'm not referring to emails going through wp_mail(). Under Settings > General, I changed from my gmail address to info@mysite.com but I still get "Welcome" and other notification emails from my gmail.

Comment: Please reread what I wrote (and I'll try to edit for some additional clarity). The two things you're talking about are *not* related. Your emails' "from" address is *not* controlled by the admin email setting.

Comment: Do you mean I need to change my administrator user email address that is located under User menu?

Comment: The email in your user profile is the email address that WP would send messages ***to***, not ***from***. I read your question to mean that you are speaking specifically about changing the "from" address that WP's emails are coming ***from***.  Is that correct?