# Is it secure to use SMTP password in .php file in WordPress website?

Tags: php, email, contact, smtp

Currently I am making feedback contact form without a plugin. Trying not to use plugins if possible. In action `.php` file there must be written server settings such as SMTP server, SMTP username etc. and eventually SMTP password. As it is not a Gmail, but hosting mailbox, SMTP password and mail password are the same. Says, that sending mail using SMTP is more secure. But if I will write all this data into my `.php` file insite WordPress platform will it be secure? What is possibility to be this data hacked?

Comment: No, it's not secure to store any sort of credentials in PHP - or anywhere that others can access. Typically you would want to create an environment variable, or perhaps an encrypted option, to protect the data.

Comment: If you have to set it up in your WP application, then use the wp-config.php to set up your SMTP info in constants that you can use in your application. see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75956/how-to-set-smtp-programmatically/276498#276498

Comment: In other forums some user adviced me to use separate email address for such purposes.